# CSS Grid with angled sides with no white space

Tags: html, css

I want to create a section for a website which is split into 4 sub sections using CSS Grid. I already have figured out how to add angled sides to the sections, however I have not figured out how to close the white spaces between each section. As far as I understand I can not go beyond 100% in the polygons and I can not use pixels because I want to have the grid responsive.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f";
  }
  
.navbar { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: a; 
}
  
.hero-slider { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: b;
}
  
.section1 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: c;
    clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section2 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: d;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section3 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: e;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section4 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: f; 
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        100% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="navbar" style="background-color: lightskyblue;">
    Navbar
  </div>
  <div class="hero-slider" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">
    Heroslider
  </div>
  <div class="section1" style="background-color: burlywood;">
    section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section2" style="background-color: darkgray;">
    section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section3" style="background-color: darksalmon;">
    section 3
  </div>
  <div class="section4" style="background-color: khaki;">
    section 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in a codepen: https://codepen.io/LuckystrikeFTW/pen/KKpJdwo

Comment: Adding margin-left: -25px; to section 2 closed the gap, i presume it works for all.

Comment: @Grumpy that seems to be the right idea, however on larger screens I notice that there is still space left. If there is no other option I could try I think I have to play around with different numbers and units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this... Its Working...

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
  position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f";
  }
  
.navbar { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: a; 
}
  
.hero-slider { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: b;
}
  
.section1 { 
    display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  width:27vw;
  height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: c;
    clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section2 { 
    display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  width:27vw;
  height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: d;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section3 { 
    display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  width:27vw;
  height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: e;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
  
.section4 { 
    display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  width:25vw;
  height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: f; 
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        100% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="navbar" style="background-color: lightskyblue;">
    Navbar
  </div>
  <div class="hero-slider" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">
    Heroslider
  </div>
  <div class="section1" style="background-color: burlywood;">
    section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section2" style="background-color: darkgray;">
    section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section3" style="background-color: darksalmon;">
    section 3
  </div>
  <div class="section4" style="background-color: khaki;">
    section 4
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why I need to specify the position of the grid container and the sections?

Comment: yeah because you are using grids right, then each grid ie your section takes his space as you specified.

Comment: Now from that section you are clipping, means the other section won't fill the remaining space

Comment: To make this happen what we are doing is disturbing the regular flow of rendering ie static and expanding each section so that it fill the space.

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Not quite since we are not specifying the position on `navbar` and `hero-slider`, though they still work as intended.

Comment: Well, we are making them to work as intended. Look we didn't define their positioning, so they'll use default ie static.

Comment: Still, having any doubt?

Comment: I guess I will look into this a bit more, but your solution works the best. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pixels and make it responsive with JavaScript.
Here is your code:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="navbar" style="background-color: lightskyblue;">
    Navbar
  </div>
  <div class="hero-slider" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">
    Heroslider
  </div>
  <div class="section1" style="background-color: burlywood;">
    section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section2" style="background-color: darkgray;">
    section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section3" style="background-color: darksalmon;">
    section 3
  </div>
  <div class="section4" style="background-color: khaki;">
    section 4
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f"
    "c c c c d d d d e e e e f f f f";
  }

.navbar { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: a; 
}

.hero-slider { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: b;
}

.section1 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: c;
    clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
  width: 360px;
}

.section2 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: d;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
  width: 360px;
}

.section3 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: e;
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        95% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
  width: 360px;
}

.section4 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: f; 
    clip-path: polygon(
        5% 0,
        100% 0,
        100% 100%,
        0 100%
    );
}
```

```
var section1 = document.getElementsByClassName('section1')[0];
var section2 = document.getElementsByClassName('section2')[0];
var section3 = document.getElementsByClassName('section3')[0];
var section4 = document.getElementsByClassName('section4')[0];

function resize() {
  section1.style = "width: " + (window.outerWidth / 4 + 15) + "px; background-color: burlywood;";
  section2.style = "width: " + (window.outerWidth / 4 + 15) + "px; background-color: darkgray;";
  section3.style = "width: " + (window.outerWidth / 4 + 15) + "px; background-color: darksalmon;";
  section4.style = "width: " + (window.outerWidth / 4 + 15) + "px; background-color: khaki;";
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/OJVdyQz