# Skewing CSS grid gaps (rows and columns)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid layout that looks like a topographical view of a city and suburbs. The rows and columns are "blocks" and the gaps are "streets". But for this to look authentic, those gaps/streets need to deviate from a strict perpendicular, and skew away from the grid here and there.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid.first {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 300px;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.grid.second {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.one.deux {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
}

.one.deux:after {
  content: " ";
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  margin-right: 80px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}

.one.trois {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}

.one.trois:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 100.5%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
}

.one.quatre {
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<main class="first grid">
  <div class="one un">1</div>
  <div class="one deux">2</div>
  <div class="one trois">3</div>
  <div class="one quatre">4</div>
  <div class="one cinq">5</div>
  <div class="one six">1</div>
  <div class="one sept">2</div>
  <div class="one huit">3</div>
  <div class="one neuf">4</div>
  <div class="one dix">5</div>
</main>

<main class="second grid">
  <div class="two un">1</div>
  <div class="two deux">2</div>
  <div class="two trois">3</div>
  <div class="two quatre">4</div>
  <div class="two cinq">5</div>
</main>
```

(Apologies for the French class names - was just trying to find another way to say 1-4!)

What I'd love to do here is skew a whole row or column gap (not just an individual div as I've done) to be on a diagonal.
That way a street looks like a street more or less.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could do this?

Comment: like the start of _Star Wars_?

Comment: actually, I've decided no, it's more like the start of _Charlie and the Chocolate Factory_ - like a map, as a matter of fact

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917856/css-grid-with-angled-sides-with-no-white-space

Comment: @cornonthecob  Can you add a link to the reference? Can't seem to find any map-like part of the intro to either Wonka/Charlie film.

Comment: Sorry @hanseuropeexpress I might be mixing things up, it might be like the end though :)